# Can't use command line after loading selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium

I've been using Selenium on Python for ages and I'm 100% sure  this is exactly what I've been doing the entire time, but suddenly it has stopped working for me. If I go into the Python interpreter as normal and type

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
<blank space>
```

instead of bringing in another `>>>` and allowing me to type, I just get this blank space and can't type anything, leaving me unable to even `driver.get` a url. The only way to regain control of the interpreter is to do `^C` or close the browser window entirely. I really don't think it's Firefox as I updated it yesterday and doing this worked fine since (to the best of my memory). Has something else changed that I've overlooked that has caused a problem with Selenium? Am I doing something massively stupid and am just looking right past it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so updating to the latest version of Selenium will solve this, possibly after you solve a couple of other issues. Personally, I first had to download the latest version of `geckodriver` and specify the location of my Firefox binary, both of which I did per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/).